# How do I remove space between characters for my text input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created an input that will let users created a username.

I want to make sure there is no spaces between characters in the input field like

```
username1
```

instead of:

```
username 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `split()` and `join()`-

```js
$(function() {
  $("input").on("keyup", function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().split(" ").join(""));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use replace function of string:

```
'username 1'.replace(' ', ''); //username1
```

Comment: Fails for multiple spaces: `'username 1 2 3'.replace(' ', ''); // 'username1 2 3'`

Answer (score 1):

```js
function removeSpaces(string) {
     return string.split(' ').join('');
    }
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" onblur="this.value=removeSpaces(this.value);">
<input type="button" value="Click">
</form>
```

where string is the value of input text.